# How do I copy a package from Debian to my PPA?

Tags: ppa, packaging, debian

I'd like to add the latest [gourmet](https://packages.debian.org/de/sid/gourmet) package from Debian sid to our [team's PPA](https://launchpad.net/~gourmet/+archive/ppa) so Ubuntu users who would like to run an up-to-date version of Gourmet can add that PPA to their software sources. (Dependency-wise, that shouldn't be much of an issue as pretty much all our current dependencies are already available in all currently supported Ubuntu versions.)

I've downloaded the `*.dsc` file and debian and orig tarballs, and even figured out I could use [this](http://packages.qa.debian.org/g/gourmet/news/20140504T173333Z.html) for the package's `source.changes` file. I also downloaded the Debian maintainer's public key so `dput` can validate the package. I then tried to upload the package to our PPA using `dput ppa:~gourmet/ppa gourmet_0.17.3-1_source.changes` (I also tried without the tilda.)
This seemed to succeed, but I didn't get a confirmation email, and no packages are now displayed at our [PPA](https://launchpad.net/~gourmet/+archive/ppa), which leads me to [believe](https://help.launchpad.net/Packaging/UploadErrors) that the package was rejected because the Debian maintainer's key is obviously not among our team members' keys.

So what's the easiest way to "copy" a package from Debian (sid) to a Launchpad PPA? Do I really need to rebuild the entire package locally before I can upload it?

Comment: BTW, as the Ubuntu development version auto-syncs its packages from Debian (before DebianImportFreeze, that is), I'll happily accept an answer telling me how to copy a package from Utopic.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You do need to rebuild the *source* package locally before uploading in order to adjust the change log and regenerate the changes file. Though since backporting a package is a pretty common task, this has been scripted. Check out the [`backportpackage` [image: Manpage icon]](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/backportpackage) command [ubuntu-dev-tools [image: Install ubuntu-dev-tools]](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/ubuntu-dev-tools) package.

To backport a package from Debian, simply provide the target distro series, PPA, and the dsc file for the package:

```
backportpackage -d trusty -u ppa:gourmet/ppa http://ftp.de.debian.org/debian/pool/main/g/gourmet/gourmet_0.17.3-1.dsc
```

It's even simpler to backport a package from one Ubuntu release to another since you don't need to find the dsc file. Let's say we want to backport from utopic to trusty:

```
backportpackage -s utopic -d trusty -u ppa:gourmet/ppa gourmet
```

Comment: Awesome! The only thing that looks a bit like a bug to me is that the package ended up in my personal PPA (~ockham-razor/ppa) even though I passed `~gourmet/ppa` as argument to the `-u` parameter. (But I was fortunately able to copy it from my PPA to the Gourmet team's via Launchpad.)

Answer (score 2):

There are a few ways to do this.

When I did this for Rhythmbox I followed the following receipe:

a. Take the source file and the debian files

[image]

b. Uncompress the source (.orig.tar.xz)

c. rename the source folder something like `rhythmbox-3.0.3`

c. uncompress the debian file (.debian.tar.xz)

d. move the debian folder under the source directory

e.  `dch -i` to change the changelog file

f. change the "unstable" package name to the name of the ubuntu target - here I've used *precise* for 12.04.  Change the version as appropriate for your app.  Here rhythmbox was 3.0.3 - so I've just added `-1~ppafossfreedom`

```
rhythmbox (3.0.3-1~ppafossfreedom) precise; urgency=low

  * rebuild

 -- fossfreedom <fossfreedom@somewheremail.com>  Thur, 07 Jun 2012 13:19:18 +0100
```

g. create a new source package: `dh_build --createorig`

h. Build just the source with your key: `debuild -S -k0xABCDEFG` where `ABCDEFG` is your key

i. upload your package for building:

```
cd ..
dput ppa:fossfreedom/rhythmbox rhythmbox_3.0.3-1_sources.changes
```

Comment: Well, that's basically rebuilding the package. Oh well. I was hoping for some easier way, but I guess there isn't any.

Comment: Take a look at the `dget` command from the `devscripts` package. It'll simplify this quite a bit.

Comment: @andrewsomething - turn that into an answer with an example :) - I would be interested to see if that can simplify my packaging as well.

Comment: Well I have a whole different answer, but you should still learn about `dget` =) The dsc file contains all the information about the other parts of the source package. So `dget` will grab everything and extract it correctly if you give it a link to the dsc file. `dget -ux http://http.debian.net/debian/pool/main/r/rhythmbox/rhythmbox_3.0.3-1.dsc`

Comment: neat answer - well done +1